# How to delete lock file if service failed to start

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, services, windows-server-2003

I have a service that has its Startup type set to automatic. However, during an unexpected restart, this service failed to start because of existing lock file. How can I delete this lock file automatically before this service attempt to start? Or how to detect and delete the lock file if service failed on startup? I'm aware of the Recovery tab in the service properties. I just need a batch file to do the deleting task on subsequent failures. If there's a more efficient way to do this, I would gladly appreciate it.

Comment: What service? Do you know the location of this lock file?

Comment: @Mokubai, this is a custom service, the lock file is located in `E:\DSpace\handle-server\txns`

Comment: I'm out at the moment but I'm pretty sure a short batch file can do this. Probably using `netsvc` to detect whether it has started (and to restart it) and a quick check on the existence of this file. I'll try and look later tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stackoverflow has an [excellent example on how to detect if a service is running and do something if not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3325123/278545):

```
for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query MyServiceName ^| findstr "        STATE"') do (
  if /I "%%H" NEQ "RUNNING" (
   REM Put your code you want to execute here
   REM For example, the following line
   del E:\DSpace\handle-server\txns
   sc start MyServiceName
  )
)
```

All you need to do is replace `MyServiceName` with the short name of your service and then put this batch file in your startup folder or simply run it when you need to, I've put in the line to delete your lock file already.